# numpy integer array and bit masking

Tags: numpy, bit

I have a numpy array storing integer values. These integer represent in single bit or groups of bits values that I need to test against some bit masks.
For instance I need to extract for all values in the array the bits 2 and 3 (LSB) and test them against all possible masks (00, 01, 10, 11). What is the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with `arr & 0b1100` ? or `(arr & 0b1100) >> 2`?

Comment: How does this help to know whether the word made of bits 2 and 3 is either 00, 01, 10 or 11?

Comment: Well the first variant gives you an array that has values 0,4,8 or12 at positions where these two bits form 00, 01, 10 or 11, respectively. The second variant makes it even easier using values 0, 1, 2, 3 for 00, 01, 10, 11. What more do you need?